# Why does [1].append(2) evaluate to None instead of [1,2]?

Tags: python

Why does `print [1].append(2)` evaluate to None?  I expect `[1,2]`

```
>>> print [1].append(2)
None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because append returns nothing (= `None`).

```
>>> print [1].append(2)
None
```

Comment: I was sitting here scratching my head thinking "this really should work" and then you came around and pointed out the obvious :)

Answer (score 3):

`array.append` doesn't return the array you appended to, it returns `None`.