# The following python codes lead to the AttributeError:, Any suggestion for rectification?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the result for comb. But the following error follows. 
Can i get any suggestions to resolve the error?

```
import math

def chirp(n):
        l=[]     
        for i in range(3141):
        i1=i/10.
        s=math.sin(n*i1)
        l=l.append(s)
    return l
l1=chirp(10,1)
l2=chirp(20,1)

l3=chirp(40,1)
comb= l1+l2+l3
print comb
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    l1=chirp(10,1)
  File "test.py", line 15, in chirp
    l=l.append(s)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \[1\].append(2) evaluate to None instead of \[1,2\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201716/why-does-1-append2-evaluate-to-none-instead-of-1-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
l = l.append(s)
```

to just

```
l.append(s)
```

`append` mutates the list, so you don't have to look at the return value (which is `None`).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're passing `chirp()` two positional arguments... are you using `,` as a decimal?

```
import math

def chirp(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(3141):
        i1 = i/10.
        s = math.sin(n*i1)
        l.append(s)
    return l

l1 = chirp(10.1)
l2 = chirp(20.1)
l3 = chirp(40.1)
comb = l1+l2+l3
print(comb)
```

This works for me with no errors. Note the in-place use of `l.append(s)`.